# Magento TAF - Cannot find page with mca "staging" in "frontend" area

Tags: testing

I keep getting: Errors: 221, Skipped: 1349 when running the automated tests..

The logs are reporting (for example):
Core_Mage_Wishlist_Wishlist::preconditionsForTests
OutOfRangeException: Cannot find page with mca "staging" in "frontend" area

'staging' being my admin url.

As far as I can see everything is properly configured in config.yml

Can anyone help?

Comment: I would say "Errors: 221, Skipped: 1349" is a big sign, that you didn't configure everything correct ;-) Did you read and follow: https://github.com/magento/taf/blob/master/MagentoTestAutomationFrameworkInstallationGuide.pdf

Comment: Hi Fabian, 
We meet again (jimains on github) :)

Thanks for the response, I will recheck my configuration against the installation guide again.